# This is not printing anything i m expecting as '*' in 6 Row

Tags: java

```
package MyPackage;

public class StarPattern {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int row;
        int column = 0;
        for (row = 0; row >= 6; row++) {
            System.out.println(" * ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This `row >= 6` should be `row < 6`., and Javascript != Java.

Comment: @VeeraKannadiga this would be the same in Javascript. Jeet, please try to search how a for loop works before write a question on SO. You need to do some research first.

Comment: @AxelH Yes. But provided code is not Javascript, which is what I'm pointing out.

Comment: @VeeraKannadiga The tag was already removed, I didn't understand what you mean there. Your ponctuation didn't helped ;) I though you where saying that this was how a for loop would work in Javascript

Comment: @AxelH I pointed out that to OP and I removed tag so he/she won't commit same mistake again :)

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the for statement declaration:

```
for (row = 0; row >= 6; row++) {
```

Formally, the `row >= 6` is called the [`Expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1). This is evaluated before the loop body (formally, the "`Statement`") is executed:

- If it is evaluated to `true`, the loop body is executed; then the `row++` is evaluated (the `ForUpdate`); then the iteration happens again.
- If it evaluates to `false`, the loop body is not executed, and execution moves on to execute the next statement after the loop.

If `row = 0`, then `row >= 6` is immediately `false`, so the loop body never executes.

I think you have perhaps assumed the other way round: that the loop stops once the `Expression` evaluates to `true`, but keeps going if it is `false`. I don't think there is a particular reason why it *couldn't* work this way; but this just isn't the way that loop semantics in Java (and many other languages) are defined.

So, simply invert the expression:

```
for (row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
               // ^  Here
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do the `System.out` every iteration that `row` is less than `6`.

```
for (row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
     System.out.println(" * ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
 int row;
    int column = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
        System.out.println(" * ");
    }
```

Comment: Please explain why it should be like this; simply dumping "corrected" code doesn't make a good answer.

Comment: It's just a basic program and basic maths so that anyone can identify the mistake by just comparing them. I don't think this need a detailed explanation.

Comment: "Give a man a fish" vs "teach a man to fish". If you don't want to give a detailed answer, just say "Change `row >= 6` to `row < 6`"; all the rest is just noise.

Comment: Is it necessary to explain a lot for a simple math problem?